# Use Imacro for write in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, imacros

i'm trying to code a script that auto writes the same thing in a ckeditor and then presses the post button, i've used the event mode, it runs smoothly, but it won't press on the post button.

this is my code:

```
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
'SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.00
URL GOTO=*link*
FRAME F=1
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY" BUTTON=0
FRAME F=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEMOVE SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(7)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>FORM>SPAN>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)>SPAN>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>DIV>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)" POINT="(236,411)"
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(7)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>FORM>SPAN>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)>SPAN>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>DIV>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)" POINT="(236,411)"
FRAME F=1
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY" CHARS="wish me luck"
FRAME F=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(7)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>FORM>FIELDSET>INPUT" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(7)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>FORM>FIELDSET>INPUT" POINT="(1464,487)"
```

the post button code is:
`<input type="submit" name="submit" class="input_submit" value="Post" tabindex="50" accesskey="s" id="submit_post" style="">`

Comment: "wish me luck" => Yeah, good luck... 

Comment: Difficult to help you if you don't post the URL of the Site/Page..., + and the 'EVENT' Mode is always very difficult to follow if you don't post any Comments in your Script, and even more difficult completely "blind" without the URL. + Your Script also looks completely strange to me, probably heavily truncated as I don't understand how you can "move" from one Frame to another one in just about 1 Pixel... ++ Grrr, buggy Site, splitting my Comment into 2 parts...

Comment: 2nd part: I don't expect an Input 'KEYPRESS' Statement to work on a 'BODY' Element, even if it's in a Frame. + Try clicking a bit more "rapidly" when you record your Actions to convert your 'MOUSEDOWN' [+'MOUSEMOVE'] + 'MOUSEUP' recorded Statements into one single 'CLICK' Event... + No Info about your Config...